# Multi Server Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, multiserver

Currently we are having 5 servers and they will be expanded to more servers in coming months. Now we are facing problem of handling them and syncing all servers. So we are using SQL Compare 10. But is there any procedure by which we can connect to these server and update those Stored Procedures at one go.

Suppose we are having 3 servers, with their IPs and Username and Passwords
Now if i change one procedure in one database in one of the server and reflect it to all the db on different server how to accomplish the same.

I was thinking of creating a procedure for which the parameters needs to be passed including the stored procedure name and then in that SP it will connect to databases and either ALTER or DELETE followed by CREATE.

Comment: I wrote a SQL Server IDE - http://www.atlantis-interactive.co.uk/products/sqleverywhere/default.aspx - which has the ability to execute the same SQL against a group of databases, but it's not an automatic thing. Or you could pay £155-375 for red gate's multi script - http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-multi-script/

Comment: Dude this is so hilarious. Loved it to the core. Thumbs up. Do you have any of the sql compare type s/w where stored procs, functions and all are looked in.

Comment: I used to - it was free - but it's now part of Pragmatic Works DBA xPress (I now work for them). SQL Everywhere hasn't become part of that suite yet so it's still available.